# Change pyzo theme by modifying base.py

Tags: python, ide

I am looking for a clean and lightweight IDE to use as a teaching tool. I personally code in IDLE / notepad++, but these will not be sufficient for the purposes of my teaching. IDEs like PyCharm are too cluttered for beginners (and I would rather use an open source IDE). After a bit of searching, I decided Pyzo is exactly what I'm looking for in an IDE.

The minor caveat is that I cannot change the theme of the editor. This is a weirdly important factor for me, and I am hopelessly fixated on this. I am running Windows 10, Python 3.7.4.

Things I have tried:

1. Installed from the provided Win binaries on Pyzo's website, then following their [instructions](https://pyzo.org/pyzo_themes.html) on how to change the theme by modifying `base.py`.
2. Uninstalled pyzo. Cloned the git repo, modified the `base.py` file, then built pyzo from source.

In both cases, the `base.py` modification in `__init__()` was as follows:

```
    # if True:  # Light vs dark
        # back1, back2, back3 = base3, base2, base1 # real solarised
        # back1, back2, back3 = "#fff", base2, base1  # crispier
        #fore1, fore2, fore3, fore4 = base00, base01, base02, base03
    if True:
        back1, back2, back3 = base03, base02, base01
        fore1, fore2, fore3, fore4 = base0, base1, base2, base3  # noqa
```

But the changes were not reflected when I started Pyzo.

I noticed that when I did (2):

```
PS C:\Users\<username>\Documents\pyzo> py -m pyzo
Started our command server
Loaded theme 'Dark'
Loaded theme 'Default'
Loaded theme 'Scintilla'
Loaded theme 'Solarized_Dark'
Loaded theme 'Solarized_Light'
```

Any tips for succeeding to change the Pyzo theme would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://pyzo.org/pyzo_themes.html

Comment: This is the link I referenced in step (1).